# Typescript - How to use full types from a generic definition?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here is my naive try to use the generic type from a parameter object of type `MyObject<P>` into a callback function.

```typescript
interface PropsType {
  value: number;
}

class MyObject<P extends PropsType> {
  readonly props: P;

  constructor(props: P) {
    this.props = props;
  }
}

function doSomething<P extends PropsType, T extends MyObject<P>>(
  object: T,
  callback: (props: P) => number
): number {
  return callback(object.props);
}

const myProps = {
  value: 21,
  otherValue: 42
}
const myObject = new MyObject(myProps);

// In the callback, props is of type PropsType
doSomething(myObject, (props) => props.otherValue);
// [ts] Property 'otherValue' does not exist on type 'PropsType'.
```

The type of `myObject` is, as expected, `MyObject<{ value: number, otherValue: number }>`, so I was expecting that the generic type would be propagated to `doSomething`. `P` would be `{ value: number, otherValue: number }`, and then `props` would be of that type too.

However, the error clearly shows that `props` is of type `PropTypes`, which is the smallest possible type for P.

Is there a way to tell the Typescript compiler to pass the full `P` definition to the callback, other than forcing the types explicitely like this?

```
doSomething<
  (typeof myObject)['props'],
  typeof myObject
>(myObject, (props) => props.otherValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting typescript to infer one type parameter based on another does not usually work. You can use a type query in this case:

```
function doSomething<T extends MyObject<PropsType>>(
    object: T,
    callback: (props: T['props']) => number
 ): number {
    return callback(object.props);
}

doSomething(myObject, (props) => props.otherValue); //works
```